# Asp.net Entity Framework Gridview Filter doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

```
protected void FilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FilterTextBox.Text))
        {
            this.GridView1.DataSource = db.Yetenekler.Local.ToBindingList();
        }
        else
        {
            var filteredData = db.Yetenekler.Local
                                 .Where(x => x.adi.Contains(this.FilterTextBox.Text));
            this.GridView1.DataSource = filteredData;
        }
    }
```

returns

Comment: What is the question? If that Gridview is not refreshing, add `this.GridView1.Databind();`

Comment: Gridview is not filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the data to the grid `.DataBind();` to refresh it.

```
protected void FilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FilterTextBox.Text))
    {
        this.GridView1.DataSource = db.Yetenekler.Local.ToBindingList();
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        var filteredData = db.Yetenekler.Local
                             .Where(x => x.adi.Contains(this.FilterTextBox.Text));
        this.GridView1.DataSource = filteredData.ToList();
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```